# Communicating with a server and Identifying users in an android app

Tags: android, mobile

Im new to programming in general and am currently trying to get started building my first mobile app on android.I am thinking of creating an app which would send requests to a server, which would then process it and load the data in the app, which the user would then view.

I have the following questions:

**Communicating with the server**

How would i program the app so that it would be able to communicate with the server (I'm planning to use a web host like godaddy/hostgator etc).

**Logging in & Identification**

How would i go about uniquely identifying each user of the app?Would it be possible to identify and create an account for any user who downloads my app from the marketplace and runs it for the first time(Maybe through the gmail account they use for the android marketplace?) or would i have to make each user manually sign up and login the first time they run my app?

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me the best way to get started and how best to go about developing such an app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json to send data to server a simple example to sending data to server to send mail..

The Server side (Php script):

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Client Side :

```
 public static void sendData(String name, String to, String from, String subject, String message)
    {
        String content = "";

        try
        {               
            /* Sends data through a HTTP POST request */
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://your.website.com");
            List <NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", to));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", from));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", subject));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

            /* Reads the server response */
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int chr;
            while ((chr = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append((char) chr);
            }
            content = sb.toString();
            in.close();

            /* If there is a response, display it */
            if (!content.equals(""))
            {
                Log.i("HTTP Response", content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**In the same way you can have your login.php and send the data to server...**